# Can CDC technology replicate changes into Kafka?

Tags: ibm-infosphere, ibm-data-replication

We need to capture and share changes from our DB2 z/OS environment into a Kafka based information hub. We have tried ETL tools to do similar but we are concerned about the impact of ETL on our source DB2 z/OS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM IDR product has numerous customers replicating data from db2 z/OS, VSAM, IMS, etc.   It has options for both remote Z access and a mainframe install each with its own advantages.  I own the Kafka Target side of this product as a disclaimer

```
I believe some z to Kafka is covered in this video has some Z to Kafka replication.
```

https://ibm.box.com/s/ur8jokg6tclsx5fcav5g86a3n57mqtd5

Originating from this link

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W8d78486eafb9_4a06_a482_7e7962f5ac59/page/IIDR%20Wiki?section=Kafka

CDC Replication has additional advantages of being able to capture the history of change to a database, in contrast to intermittent snapshots.  Some applications for this are auditing, or moving average performance monitoring in real-time.

ON the Kafka side a number of different formats are included, with the ability to define just about any messaging behaviour desired.

There is a presentation called expose your data not your database given at an IDUG conference you might be interested in.